# Aligning image in LinearLayout

Tags: android, image, android-linearlayout

I have `LinearLayout` and I want to put into it `ImageView`. Is there any simple way how to put this image on the right side of the screen? Now, the image is placed to the left, padding and marking don't solve this, because this should be done dynamically, the image is each time different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the gravity attribute to `right`?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. I have Theme.Dialog Activity and I need to align image to the right window end. In my list of checkboxes it is still aligned to the middle.

Comment: Make sure your `layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: @Waypoint Please post your XML in your question, there are too many possibilities to guess what is happening. Tag me with `@Sam` in a comment when you do.